# MongoDB installation on Mac OS X 10.11, with MacPorts

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, installation, macports

I am trying to install MongoDB on my computer running Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

My Apache + PHP configuration was already working correctly.

I installed MongoDB and PHP drivers for MongoDB through MacPorts:

```
sudo port install mongodb
sudo port install php55-mongodb
```

Installation ran correctly.

I added mongodb.so file to the extensions loaded in the php.ini file:

```
extension=/opt/local/lib/php55/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongodb.so
```

When I run phpinfo() function in php file, mongodb extension seems to be loaded correctly:
[image]

I tried to test my connexion by initializing a MongoClient instance:

```
<?php

    $mongoDB = new MongoClient();

    var_dump($mongoDB);

?>
```

Unfortunately, I got a *HTTP ERROR 500*, and I got the following line in my Apache logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in ...
```

Did I make something wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing things up here? It seems you're trying to use the Mongo PHP extension which provides MongoClient (http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) but you actually installed the MongoDB PHP extensions (see http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem.

As @neverpanic and @Zagonine made me understand, **php-mongodb** and **php-mongo** are not the same extension.

If you want to use old PHP driving classes, you should use **php-mongo** package instead of the very new **php-mongodb**.

Trying to install latest **php-mongo** extension, I had an other problem related to OpenSSL. To bypass it, I installed an old version of **php-mongo** extension:

```
sudo /usr/local/pear/bin/pecl install mongo-1.5.8
```

Hopefully it will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

On most of site I saw you need to add the extension `mongo.so` and not `mongodb.so` in your `php.ini`.
If it's not solved your problem, I recommand you to install MongoDB Drive with [PELC](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/).

Run command line:

```
$ sudo pecl install mongo
```

And add this line to your `php.ini`:

```
extension=mongo.so
```

[Doc php.net Mongo Installation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx)